Mantine LineChart tooltip is showing up transparent
I am using the Mantine LineChart component and the tooltip is not showing up like the examples.
Below is my code. I cannot figure out what makes it different from the demo code on https://mantine.dev/charts/line-chart/ but the examples have the tooltip in a box with a border, drop shadow, and white background and mine doesn't have any of that.
<LineChart
  m="md"
  h={300}
  data={trends}
  dataKey="timestamp"
  curveType="linear"
  series={[
    { name: "Route A", color: "blue" },
    { name: "Route B", color: "red" },
    { name: "Loop de Loop", color: "green" },
  ]}
/>

A lot of the styling in general seems to be missing, the axis labels don't format right and the dots on the far right of the chart get cut in half. 

The answer was that you need to import the charts style separately from normal mantine core styles.
import '@mantine/charts/styles.css';
